# Is it possible to have "drill down" links (using HTTP?) to a desktop based MS Access based application

Tags: ms-access, url, legacy

We have a legacy system written in MS Access which is being replaced with a web based application.

The old MS Access system still needs to be functional for some reference

Is there a way to provide a link that will cause MS Access to open in a certain page / report / etc (as a web application probably would)?

e.g. Just like a mailto: link can be used to open Outlook... or opening netmeeting by link, perhaps there is some out of the box or 3rd party utility that can translate a URL to open a specific Access form or report?

Comment: You can create shortcuts to objects within an Access database by dragging them to the desktop. That shortcut could then be used to launch the database. Is that what you're looking for? It's not at all clear from what you're saying, as it seems simpler to just program the startup of the Access app to load the relevant form/report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mailto: is a *protocol* separate from http.  I don't think you can do what you want using http.

However, if you are truly motivated you *might* be able to do this by implementing your own protocol.  Instructions for doing this with Mozilla Firefox can be found at [Writing a Mozilla Protocol Handler](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/projects/netlib/new-handler.html) and, more recently, [Writing a Firefox Protocol Handler](http://mike.kaply.com/2011/01/18/writing-a-firefox-protocol-handler/).

Of course this would require your users to use Firefox if they wanted to take advantage of this feature.

The opposite approach (ie, putting links from your Access app to your web app) is infinitely simpler.  Just check the help file for `FollowHyperlink` and the Hyperlink Address/Subaddress property of form Label controls.